# Jenkins проверка входящих параметров на соответствие

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Есть Jenkins job, в него передаётся string параметр phaseJobId и возвращается назад Stage.
Параметр phaseJobId имеет валидные значения, которые обрабатываются в коде джобы (код приведён ниже) 'Prepare', 'Deploy', 'Start_Testing'
**Вопрос:**
Как сделать так, чтобы Job возвращал Fail при любом значении, отличном от валидного?

```
@Library('Xxx-pipeline-utils') _

pipeline {
    agent any
    
    parameters {
        string(name: 'phaseJobId', defaultValue: "", description: "Stage name to be failed ('Prepare', 'Deploy', 'Start_Testing')")
        string(name: 'stage', defaultValue: "", description: "Stage to return")
    }
    
    environment {
        stageName = 'stage'
        wfUrl='192.168.100.31:8080'
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Prepare'){
            steps {
                script {
                    if('Prepare'.equals(stage)) {
                        setXxxVarOnServer(wfUrl, phaseJobId, stageName, 'Deploy')
                    }
                    sleep(1)
                }
            }
        }

        stage ("Deploy"){
            steps {
                script {
                    if('Deploy'.equals(stage)) {
                        setXxxVarOnServer(wfUrl, phaseJobId, stageName, 'Start_Testing')
                    }
                    sleep(3)
                }
            }
        }

        stage ("Start_Testing"){
            steps {
                script {
                    if('Start_Testing'.equals(stage)) {
                        setXxxVarOnServer(wfUrl, phaseJobId, stageName, 'Prepare')
                    }
                    sleep(2)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо разобраться что такое валидное значение

А перевод джоба в FAILED в блеке script там где вам надо:

```
if (phaseJobId=="valid") {
    currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
}
```

Comment: А можете уточнить, как это будет записываться, если нужно чтобы failed возвращался при любом значении кроме 'Prepare', 'Deploy', 'Start_Testing'

Comment: по синтаксису подходит так, но почему-то ломается всё прохождение при любых значениях 
stage('Checking'){
            steps {
                script {
                    if (phaseJobId!="Prepare" || phaseJobId!="Deploy" || phaseJobId!="Start_Testing") {
    setDpmVarOnServer(wfUrl, phaseJobId, stageName, 'ALLALA')
    }

Comment: @Ilya, для нескольких вариантов вместо оператора ИЛИ можно использовать contains:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_lists_contains.htm
В общем, блок script это groovy код и там можно творить все что умеет груви